# How to use the same validation fields in two components?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-components

I want to optimize my application so as not to use the same validation fields in two components. 
I use the fields for checking `"title"` and `"url"` in the component `"GalleryAddComponent"` (when I add an element) and the same fields for checking `"title"` and `"url"` in the component `"GalleryItemComponent"` (when I edit the component). In components, only the buttons in the form are different, in `"GalleryAddComponent"` there is a button "add" which calls the method of adding an element, and in the component `"GalleryItemComponent"`  button "updatePost" which saves the changes in the element.

**I understand that the fields need to be transferred to a separate component and connected in the forms of the components: `"GalleryAddComponent"` and `"GalleryItemComponent"`. But how to do it correctly to save the validation of the buttons and their logic. Help please understand how to implement this idea and if you can set an example in "StackBlitz".**

**Link to the structure of my project: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/gorillasz/gallery)**

**template of GalleryAddComponent:**

```html
<h3>Add new product</h3>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" minlength="1" #title/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].invalid && (angForm.controls['title'].dirty || angForm.controls['title'].touched)"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].errors.required">
                    Title is required.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4">Picture Address (url)</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="url" #url pattern="https?://.+"
                       title="Include http://"/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].invalid && (angForm.controls['url'].dirty || angForm.controls['url'].touched)"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
                Address(url) is required.
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].errors.required ">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group but-group">
                <button (click)="addPost(title.value, url.value);  angForm.reset(title.value, url.value)"
                        [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Add
                </button>
                <a routerLink="/gallery" class="btn btn-danger">Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**code of GalleryAddComponent:**

```js
export class GalleryAddComponent {
    angForm: FormGroup;
    isAdded: boolean = false;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private galleryService: GalleryService) {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm(): void {
        this.angForm = this.fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            url: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    addPost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.galleryService.add(title, url).subscribe(res => {
            this.isAdded = true;
        });
    }
}
```

**template of GalleryItemComponent:**

```html
        <h4>Edit your post</h4>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form [formGroup]="angFormEd" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="titleEd" #titleEd
                    />
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="angFormEd.controls['titleEd'].invalid && (angFormEd.controls['titleEd'].dirty || angFormEd.controls['titleEd'].touched)"
                     class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="angFormEd.controls['titleEd'].errors.required">
                        Title is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4">Picture Address (url)</label>
                    <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="urlEd" #urlEd pattern="https?://.+"
                           title="Include http://"/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="angFormEd.controls['urlEd'].invalid && (angFormEd.controls['urlEd'].dirty || angFormEd.controls['urlEd'].touched)"
                     class="alert alert-danger">
                    Address(url) is required.
                    <div *ngIf="angFormEd.controls['urlEd'].errors.required ">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group but-group">
                    <input type="button"
                           (click)="updatePost(titleEd.value, urlEd.value)"
                           [disabled]=" angFormEd.invalid"
                           class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Post">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**code of GalleryItemComponent:**

```js
export class GalleryItemComponent implements OnInit {
   pic: Picture;
   angFormEd: FormGroup;

     constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private galleryService: GalleryService, private fb: FormBuilder,) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createFormEd();
        this.showPost();
    }

    createFormEd(): void {
        this.angFormEd = this.fb.group({
            titleEd: ['', Validators.required],
            urlEd: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    showPost(): void {
        this.route.data.subscribe(params => {
            this.pic = params.post;
            this.angFormEd.setValue({titleEd: params.post.title, urlEd: params.post.url});
        })
    }
    updatePost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.update(title, url, params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.id === this.pic.id) {
                    this.pic.title = title;
                    this.pic.url = url;
                } 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to create a reusable validator, write a [Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) that does the validation. This way you can attach the validator to any form field, simply by adding an attribute to the input.

But if you want to create a reusable component that contains the entire form...

First thing I recommend is to create an interface with the fields that your form contains. This helps you to easily pass the data between components.

```typescript
export interface GalleryItem {
  title: string;
  url: string;
}
```

Then you have to create a child component that contains your form along with the submit button. The role of this component is to get the input from the user, validates it and if its ok sends it back to the parent component, which may be `AddComponent` or `EditComponent`. The parent component decides what to do with this data. If its the `Edit` page, parent component should first fetch the previous data and pass it to the child component in order to fill the form. Button labels also can be passed from parent to the child.

There are many ways of components interaction you can choose. If you aren't familiar with passing data between components, I strongly recommend you to read the [Angular docs](https://angular.io), especially the [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) section.

[sample code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-interaction-stackoverflow-01)

Comment: I want to create a reusable component that contains the entire form. 
Can you show some example in "StackBlitz" what would I understand

Comment: @IgorShvets I've created a sample app in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
    selector: 'control-error-message',
    host: {
        '[class.error_msg]': 'showErrorMessage'
    },
    template: `<span *ngIf="showErrorMessage">{{displayMessage}}</span>`
})
export class ErrorMessageComponent {

    @Input() control: FormControl;

    errorMessage: string;
    displayMessage: string;
    showErrorMessage: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges) {

        if (this.control) {
            this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    this.setErrorMessage(this.control);
                }
            )
        }
    }

    getControlName(c: AbstractControl): string | null {
        const formGroup = c.parent.controls;
        return Object.keys(formGroup).find(name => c === formGroup[name]) || null;
    }

    setErrorMessage(control: FormControl) {
        this.errorMessage = "";
        if (control.errors) {
            for (let propertyName in control.errors) {
                if (propertyName.toLowerCase() == "required") {
                    this.displayMessage = this.getControlName(control) + " field is required";
                    this.showErrorMessage = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in html you can have something like

```
<form [formGroup]="angFormEd" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" minlength="1" #title/>
     <control-error-message [control]="formGroupObject.get('title')"></control-error-message>
</div>
```

This is not tested or a working code, I have removed few lines of code to make it look simpler and clearer.
You don't have to introduce this line in your html:

```
<div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].invalid && (angForm.controls['title'].dirty || angForm.controls['title'].touched)"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].errors.required">
                    Title is required.
                </div>
            </div>
```

All styling will be taken care by "error_msg" class applied on host, if dere is an error. Plus the message will be shown just below the input field.

Note: I have just copy pasted my code and removed few things, understand the idea and implement it based on your requirement